# Unitary transformation to triangularize 2 matrices at the same time

Tags: linear-algebra, unitary-matrices, triangularization

I am trying to show that:
Given 2 complex non-singular matrices $A$ and $B$, there exist two unitary matrices $Q$ and $Z$ s.t. $Q^*AZ$ and $Q^*BZ$ are simultaneously upper triangular.

Thank for your help.

Comment: Please use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: The word "triangularize" usually refers to situations when matrices are brought to this form under *similarity*. Apparently [this](https://people.inf.ethz.ch/arbenz/ewp/Slides/slides5.pdf) presentation (see page 17 and later) contains an algorithm for QZ decomposition.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a proof of this statement, it can be found in the paper [G.W. Stewart, On the Sensitivity of the Eigenvalue Problem A x= Bx, SIA M J. Numer.
Anal. 9, 1972, 669-686](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2156219), Theorem 3.1.